# python quiz with jinja

Tags: python, jinja2

i'm learning at moment python and for a exercise i have to build a quiz with jinja.
for the quiz i have to build a random function, so that the questions comes random. but i have the problem that my codes don't run the right way. with my code, i get the Error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType"
does anybody have a tip, how it might work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2
import random


template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape=False)

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

def write(self, *a, **kw):
    return self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

def render_str(self, template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)

def render(self, template, **kw):
    return self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

def render_template(self, view_filename, params=None):
    if not params:
        params = {}
    template = jinja_env.get_template(view_filename)
    return self.response.out.write(template.render(params))



class MainHandler(BaseHandler):


  def get(self):
        city = cities[secret]
        return self.render_template("index.html", params={"picture" : city.picture, "country" : city.country})

    def post(self):
        capital = self.request.get("capital")
        city = cities[secret]
        if capital == city.name:
            return self.write("That's right :)")
        else:
            return self.write("Sorry, it's wrong")

    class City(object):
        def __init__(self, name, country, picture):
            self.name = name
            self.country = country
            self.picture = picture

cities = [City (name="Vienna""Berlin", country="Austria""Germany", picture="http://www.mpnpokertour.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Slider-Vienna.png""http://polpix.sueddeutsche.com/bild/1.1406949.1355282590/940x528/berlin-staedtetipps-szkorrespondenten.jpg")]
secret = random.seed(len(cities))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. When seeking debugging help, you should 1) post the full error, including stack trace, if you have an error, 2) post the desired behavior (and 3. post it in the form of a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but what you posted is good enough).

Comment: the error code is 
 File "*\quiz\main.py", line 35, in get
    city = cities[secret]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
secret = random.seed(len(cities))
```

This sets `secret` to `None`, because the seed function returns nothing.
You probably confused [seed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) with [randint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint). Seed is used to initialize the random number generator (usually unneeded as python does it automatically), while randint picks a random number and returns it.

```
secret = random.randint(0, len(cities) - 1)
```

→ this will set `secret` to a random integer between 0 and the number of cities (minus one), inclusive.